# rspec, validate the actual Expectation parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, mocking, expectations

Is it possible to validate the actual parameter received by a mock objects method parameter? I cannot do a direct comparison because i'm using Fabricate and converting the object into a serialised format.

for example:

```
expect(user).to have_received(:add).with(valid_user())
```

so in that case `valid_user()` would accept the parameter, validate and return a boolean, to verify a valid value was passed into `user.add()`

can something like that be done?

So far I've been reading the documentation in https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks regarding Argument Matchers

Edit: in my specific case, the argument is a quite large string. I would like to validate that the string is valid by potentially running a regex against the string. So i would like to run the argument through a validation method which simply returns true/false.

Comment: actually, I think what I need in my case is something like: `expect(user).to have_received(:add).with(/regexcheck/)`, i can use the regex check to validate the only argument accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom matches in with() as shown in the spec docs https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/setting-constraints/matching-arguments#using-a-custom-matcher

Comment: Link is dead. This is why link-only answers are not allowed.